# How to correctly setup Vertical scroll snap css

Tags: html, css, snap

I want to create a website. with multiple sections with a width of 100vw and a height of 100vh.I also want a mandatory y (vertical) snap for these sections. I have checked out many tutorials, But my code doesn't seem to work. Any help is highly appreciated.

Current code

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: white;
}

body .content {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100%;
  scroll-snap-type: mandatory;
  scroll-snap-points-y: repeat(300px);
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
}

body .content section {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  border: 1px solid black;
  scroll-snap-align: start;
}
```

```html
<div class='content'>
  <section>1</section>
  <section>2</section>
  <section>3</section>
  <section>4</section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just reading the [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Scroll_Snap/Browser_compat) on this makes it seem like this feature is highly inconsistent between browsers, but following their guide I managed to make your snippet work with these changes:

```
body .content {
  height: 100vh; /* was 100% */
  overflow: auto; /* added */
}
```

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: white;
}

body .content {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  scroll-snap-points-y: repeat(300px);
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
  scroll-snap-type: mandatory;
  overflow: auto;
}

body .content section {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  border: 1px solid black;
  scroll-snap-align: start;
}
```

```html
<div class='content'>
  <section>1</section>
  <section>2</section>
  <section>3</section>
  <section>4</section>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I looked at the mozilla docs before publishing this question, but it was a little bit confusing. Thanks again for the solution.