# cannot get css vertical scroll snapping to work

Tags: html, css, scroll-snap, scroll-snap-type

I have tried like 5 different tutorials at this point but none of them have gotten scroll snapping to work in my project. I left some things I have tried in comments and included my most recent attempt

```
html{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Noto Sans', sans-serif;
    scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

/*
.scroll_container{
    overflow-y: scroll;
    scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
}*/

section{
    /*min-height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;*/
    scroll-snap-align: start;
    height: 100vw;

}
```

```
<body>
        <div class="scroll_container">
        <section>
            <h1>Tyler Olson</h1>
        </section>
        <section class = "new1_section">
            <h2>new section1</h2>
            <p>lkhrogisahlkjsbhdgnbuherldofiubnweroiubndsoiufbdpsoibro unbowbbvbidsjb</p>
        </section>
        <section class = "new2_section">
              <h2>new section2</h2>
              <p>lkhrogisahlkjsbhdgnbuherldofiubnweroiubndsoiufbdpsoibro unbowbbvbidsjb</p>
        </section>
        <section class = "new3_section">
            <h2>new section 3</h2>
            <p>alksdfj;lgsfakhg;ldskajgf;dlsakjhgk;lsahgl;fsakhg;lsakhfg;ljsaghs;alkgh</p>
        </section>
        <section class = "new4_section">
            <h2>new section 4</h2>
            <p>as;ldkfj;alskfhgd;lskjahg;lsakhjfg;lsakfhg;alsfjhg;alsjfhg;laskfghj</p>
            <br>
            <p><a href="https://www.freepik.com/free-vector/data-stream-digital-binary-code-background_12686653.htm#query=programming%20background&position=5&from_view=keyword">Image by starline</a> on Freepik</p>
        </section>
    </div>
    </body>
```

please let me know any recommendations you have, thank you in advance

[How to correctly setup Vertical scroll snap css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69280233/how-to-correctly-setup-vertical-scroll-snap-css)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MsmvhpBXosM&t=200s
these are two of the guide/posts I've tried to follow but couldn't get working

Comment: When I demonstrate, the effect is the same as in the video. When scrolling <section> to 80%, the next <section> will automatically come up. What effect do you want to achieve?

Comment: Well it didn't do at all what he did in the video when I tried to adapt my site to add it, I think I'm going to try creating a seperate folder and copying all of his code exactly, making sure it works correctly, and then slowly making all of my changes to it till I get the desired resilts

Comment: I answered an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74421486/14556734) in this question, I don't know if it is close to the effect you want.

Comment: yes that is the effect I am looking for